# Rollup plugin that correct handles SCSS exports used in React

Tags: reactjs, sass, rollupjs

I'm looking for a way to use SCSS exports in my project which I'm building using rollup.

Currently this works in React like so:

```
//Colors.scss
$black: #000000;

:export {
  black: $black;
}
```

```
//Component.js
import Colors from '../Colors.scss'

console.log(Colors.black)
```

But I can't seem to get this to work with rollup. Are they any plugins out there that correctly handle this use case?

Here are the plugins I've tried so far:
`rollup-plugin-styles`
`rollup-plugin-scss`
`rollup-plugin-sass`

Answer (score 0):

Using storybook, lerna, and vite I ran into trouble because the old API [was deprecated](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/14819#issuecomment-1786923323) and `rollup-plugin-sass` (the other two you listed don't seem as well maintained) was conflicting with that.

Either `lerna run build` or `storybook build` would fail with `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './style.[css|scss|sass]' does not provide an export named 'default'` or `RollupError: Could not resolve "./style.[css|scss|sass]?inline" …` depending on whether I appended `?inline` accourding to the [Vite docs](https://main.vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html#removed-deprecated-apis).

To get them to stop conflicting, I added to a global rollup config:

```
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";

…

    plugins: [
      
      replace({
        values: {
          ".scss?inline": ".scss",
          // Normally shipped with vue.js packages but it won't work in browser
          "process.env.NODE_ENV": '"production"',
        },
        delimiters: ['\\b', '\\b(?!\\.)', ""],
        preventAssignment: true,
      }),

…
```

No idea whether this will be useful to you since you didn't say what wasn't working, but I combed the whole internet for a solution to this before I came up with the above.